# How to perform an update based on the results of a having clause of a group by

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to get the following code to work. I want update TranID only if there are duplicates

```
update Test set TranID=(select MAX(TranID)+1 from Test)
from Test
group by TranID
having COUNT(TranID)>1
```

Comment: Does the table have more columns? I assume that you want to avoid duplicate `TranID`s caused by the update also? Please show sample dara and a desired result.

Comment: Please post `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    DECLARE @TranID INT = ( SELECT  MAX(TranID) 
                        FROM    Test
                      );
    WITH    List
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY TranID ) + @TranID NewTranID ,
                        TranID
               FROM     Test T
               WHERE    T.TranID IN ( SELECT    T2.TranID
                                      FROM      Test T2
                                      GROUP BY  T2.TranID
                                      HAVING    COUNT(T2.TranID) > 1 )
             )
    UPDATE  List
    SET     TranID = NewTranID
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, this should work:

```
UPDATE Test
 SET TranID = (select MAX(TranID)+1 from Test)
FROM Test
  inner JOIN (SELECT TranID
             FROM Test 
             GROUP BY TranID
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) d ON d.TranID = Test.TranID
```

Comment: This updates everything that matches to the exact same value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to update all but one for each TranID matching set, then try this solution.

```
-- Setup your data
IF OBJECT_ID('Test', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Test;
CREATE TABLE Test (TranID int)
INSERT Test (TranID) VALUES (1),(2),(2),(3),(3),(3),(6),(6)
GO

DECLARE @MaxTranID int = (SELECT MAX(TranID) FROM Test)

;WITH test_temp (idx, TranID)
AS
(
    -- Get a unique identifier for each record
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY TranID ) as idx
          ,TranID
      FROM Test
)
,test_temp_dupes (TranID, MinIdx)
AS
(
    -- Get the first record in each TranID group
    SELECT TranID
          ,MIN(idx) as MinIdx
      FROM test_temp
     GROUP BY TranID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

-- Assign new values to each TranID in the dupe groups except the first record
UPDATE A
   SET A.TranID = A.idx + @MaxTranID
  FROM test_temp A
  JOIN test_temp_dupes B
    ON A.TranID = B.TranID
   AND A.idx   <> B.MinIdx

-- See your results
SELECT * FROM Test
```